# How to select column based on other table column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: Table1 & Table2. 
Both the tables are given below:

here is `table1`

```
+----+----------+
| id | t1_title |
+----+----------+
| 1  | AAA      |
+----+----------+
| 2  | BBB      |
+----+----------+
| 3  | CCC      |
+----+----------+
```

here is `table2`

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id | t2_title | t1_IDs |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | John     | 1,3    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | Sam      | 2      |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | Monty    | 1,2    |
+----+----------+--------+
| 4  | Rose     | 2,3    |
+----+----------+--------+
```

Now I want to get the `table1.title` (like AAA,BBB,CCC) based on the `table2.t1_IDs` , something like this:

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | t2_title | t1_titles |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | John     | AAA,CCC   |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 2  | Sam      | BBB       |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 3  | Monty    | AAA,BBB   |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 4  | Rose     | BBB,CCC   |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Ids should not be stored in string lists.  Numbers should not be stored as strings.  Foreign key relationships should be properly declared!

Comment: First thing to do is not design a table that stores ids to another table as a comma delimited list. You need a pivot table to create a many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  a.id,
        t2_title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(b.t1_title ORDER BY b.id)
FROM    table2 a
        INNER JOIN table1 b
            ON FIND_IN_SET(b.t1_title, a.t1_IDs) > 0
GROUP   BY a.id,a.t2_title
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7YmAs2goqXzyAkWipnmP25/0)